# How to make groups using latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: python, machine-learning, coordinates, classification

I have a time series dataset where the pickup and drop off latitude and longitude coordinates are given.
Since coordinates of a city hardly vary, how to categorize them in python?

I want to make groups so that Classification algorithm can be applied.

I am pasting a single row of pick up and drop off longitude and latitude coordinates of New York city.

-73.973052978515625 40.793209075927734  -73.972923278808594 40.782520294189453

I have fixed the range of latitude from 40.6 to 40.9 and longitude range from -73.9 to -74.25

Now, I want to make them into groups so that classification algorithm can be applied.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: It sounds like you need a kind of group by on a geographical basis. Try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254704/pandas-group-bins-of-data-per-longitude-latitude) or [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132955/grouping-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-by-city-neighborhood). It's just a blind try. Can you give us more details?

Comment: How about use KNN method in sklearn, it's a basic classifying method in machine learning.

Comment: @TomDalton I have no idea how to proceed with this part.

Comment: @floatingpurr Latitude and longitude coordinates of New York City are given on the basis of pickup and drop off locations of trips.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I'm afraid that without a clear example about data and your desired output no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @floatingpurr I have edited my question.

Comment: What is the output you want?

Comment: @floatingpurr Is it necessary to make groups of coordinates let's say 40.61 to 40.70, 40.71 to 40.80 for the classification algorithm to work. As I have done linear regression and accuracy is not that good, so thinking of random forest or can you suggest me a better alternative?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I answered to your question

Comment: Thanks for this help.

Comment: @AshishChoudhary feel free to mark the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can insert you coordinates in a list of `tuples` called `coordinates`. Please note that I have appended also a couple of coordinates out of range. Here is the code:

```
coordinates = [
    (-73.973052978515625,40.793209075927734),
    (-73.972923278808594,40.782520294189453), 
    (-75.9,40.7)
    ]

filtered = list()

# filtering coordinates
for c in coordinates:
    if  -74.25 <= c[0] <= -73.9 and 40.6 <= c[1] <= 40.9:
        filtered.append(c)

print filtered # here you have your filtered coordinates
```

Output:

```
[(-73.97305297851562, 40.793209075927734), (-73.9729232788086, 40.78252029418945)]
```